# How to measure the page loading time in yaml file by cucumber with watir-webdriver performance gem?

Tags: performance, cucumber, yaml, watir-webdriver

I want to measure the time of loading the page. I use watir-webdriver performance gem and this code:

```
5.times do
  @b.goto ("#{@host}")    
  puts "Load Time: #{@b.performance.summary[:response_time]/1000.000} seconds."
end
```

But now I need to produce yalm file, that collect the time information of the cucumber-test for my statistic.

Comment: Are you already getting the performance information you need? Are you just asking how to output to the yaml file?

Answer (score 2):

```
def write_to_file(p)
  File.open('performance.txt', 'a') {|file| file.write("#{p} - #{@b.performance.summary[:response_time]/1000.000} seconds\n") }
end

@page = "google.com"
write_to_file(@page)
```